# RC4 encryption - CommonCrypto (Objective-C) vs PHP

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, algorithm, encryption

I have a XML file on a server encrypted with the RC4 algorithm (http://rc4crypt.devhome.org)

```
function encrypt ($pwd, $data, $ispwdHex = 0)
    {
        if ($ispwdHex)
            $pwd = @pack('H*', $pwd); // valid input, please!

        $key[] = '';
        $box[] = '';
        $cipher = '';

        $pwd_length = strlen($pwd);
        $data_length = strlen($data);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {
            $key[$i] = ord($pwd[$i % $pwd_length]);
            $box[$i] = $i;
        }
        for ($j = $i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
        {
            $j = ($j + $box[$i] + $key[$i]) % 256;
            $tmp = $box[$i];
            $box[$i] = $box[$j];
            $box[$j] = $tmp;
        }
        for ($a = $j = $i = 0; $i < $data_length; $i++)
        {
            $a = ($a + 1) % 256;
            $j = ($j + $box[$a]) % 256;
            $tmp = $box[$a];
            $box[$a] = $box[$j];
            $box[$j] = $tmp;
            $k = $box[(($box[$a] + $box[$j]) % 256)];
            $cipher .= chr(ord($data[$i]) ^ $k);
        }
        return $cipher;
    }
```

Here is the objective-C code I use to decrypt :

```
      NSData *dataToDecrypt = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/fileCrypted.xml"]] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        const void *vplainText;
        size_t plainTextBufferSize;


            plainTextBufferSize = [dataToDecrypt length];
            vplainText = [dataToDecrypt bytes];


        CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
        uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
        size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
        size_t movedBytes = 0;

        bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
        bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
        memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

        NSString *key = @"mykey";
        //NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
        const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
        const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

size_t keyLength = [[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length]; 
        ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                           kCCAlgorithmRC4,
                           0,
                           vkey,
                           kCCKeySizeDES,
                           nil,
                           vplainText,
                           plainTextBufferSize,
                           (void *)bufferPtr,
                           bufferPtrSize,
                           &movedBytes);
        if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
        /*else*/ if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
        else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
        else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
        else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
        else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
        else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";

        NSString *result = [[ NSString alloc ] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIEncoding];
```

Logs output : SUCCESS but my result is not good (I tested many encoding but ASCII seems to be the good, cf. PHP function ord ...)

Are my both RC4 implementation standard ?

Edit: removed IV in Objective-C code
Edit2: Objective-C KeyLength = password data length, removed option

Comment: Your objectiv-c code uses an initialization vector _and_ a password. I don't see an IV in your php code, only the default initialization `$box[$i] = $i;`

Comment: Thanks a lot,
You're alright, although the decryption still doesn't work...

I think I missing something, but I'm really not comfortable with encryption.. Is kCCOptionPKCS7Padding the good option ? 

I'm lost, but I must make the decryption working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know what you're doing in cryptography, then "rolling-your-own" is a sure fire receipe for disaster. You don't have to believe me, read John Viega on [The Cult of Schneier](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/01/the-cult-of-schneier.html) about general programmers who try to "roll their own" cryptography. Paraphrased: **Don't do it.**

Since this is a file, and I'm guessing a reasonable small file, you can use more standard and higher level libraries using standards such as SSL (OpenSSL and others) or OpenPGP (GPG, etc.) to do the necessary encryption / decryption. I believe there is library or module support for SSL in both Objective-C (or the iPhone environment) and PHP.

In particular about RC4, it is a stream cipher that is deceptively simple to write, but incredibility easy to mess up in its implementation details. See [The Misuse of RC4 in Microsoft Word and Excel](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2005/Jan/90), and [Can you recommend RC4 128-bit encrypted software?](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid14_gci957269,00.html) for an well known historic example, and a recommendation of security / cryptography expert (former CTO and co-founder of PGP Corp.).

---

**Added:**

The keysize in the php script is based on the raw length of the password data. It also does not use any PKCS7 Padding, so I believe that field should be zero (0) (CCryptor doesn't support padding of stream ciphers, and the php version certainly doesn't use it). In your code CCCrypt used a keysize of 8 bytes (64* bits), whereas I believe you want it to be the length (in bytes) of the password (binary data).

There is no [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) or hash of the data so the functions won't be able to determine valid from invalid decodings.

I think this will get you closer to compatibility with this insecure implementation of RC4 (RC4crypt in PHP).

- - DES uses [56-bits of key from 64-bits of key inpu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Key_schedule)t.

Comment: Hi, 

first of all, thanks for taking the time to advice me, and I think you're alright.

But the matter is : I don't have any choice, the content provider is encrypting the file with RC4 crypt in PHP, and give me the key.

I can't make him change the encryption for me because others services use the file. I don't think this is a good way, I usually advice to use an API system with a public / private key with a time variable.

So I know what I'm doing is not the good way. But I must decode the file on the iPhone this way :-/

All the best.

Comment: Hi mctylr,
Thanks for helping me, I added the variable keyLength and removed the PKCS7 Padding option. ------ For valid or invalid decodings, if I get a valid XML, I pretty sure that the decoding is valid. ---- Can the error come from encoding ? I feel really stupid... :(

Comment: If you mean can you introduce error from conversion of text encoding of data strings, then yes. I don't know Objective-C, so I am unclear about your usage of UTF-8 strings (`initVec UTF8String`), and then in the last line *encoding:NSASCIIEncoding*. The encryption and decryption treats both the input and output as a binary data, so working with an array of C-style `char` would be best if possible.

Comment: BTW, here are some test vectors you can use for testing both implementations
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Test_vectors

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mctylr, Avoid rolling your own whenever possible. If you need RC4, use a pre-built/tested library: [OpenSSL RC4](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rc4.html#). You can replace your entire code with about 3 lines.